# Dynamic memory allocation for Union

Tags: c

I have a union of following type, for example

```
typedef union
{
     typedef struct
     {
          short int a;
          short int b;
          short int c;
          short int d
     }str1;
     short int my_array[x];
}union1;
```

Here I want to allocate memory to array dynamically which will be always more than what `str1` needs. What are the changes that I need to apply in the above code so that I will be able to allocate memory to `my_array` dynamically?

Comment: `short int *my_array;` and then `x.my_array = malloc(sizeof(short int) * n);`

Comment: Will that even compile? Anyhow, the inner `typedef` is pointless, as it is just a `typedef`, not a `struct` member. And the `[x]` at `my_array` is strange as well.

Comment: You're purpose here is unclear, and the use of a `union` is possibly inadequate for what you're hoping to achieve.

Comment: @barak: Do u mean that inner typedef is not necessary? and x was written for indicating that it can be of any size or size does not matter here.

Comment: I mean, what are you trying to achieve, and why do you need to do it with a `union`?

Comment: @barak :Actually I did the same what u suggested in your 1st comment and it is compiling without error. But when I actually dumped it on controller and saw using debug that it is not getting allocated. Actually I came to conclusion as my purpose is not fulfilled.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't recall suggesting anything here...

Comment: @barak : sorry it was Alter, I think u can see his comment

Comment: how about     short int my_array[sizeof(str1)/sizeof(short int) + x];     ?

Comment: @barakmanos :About my purpose:I am using this for handling mono bitmap file. struct is for file header access and array is for filling data and copying file.

Answer (score 1):

What I'd do is make `my_array` a pointer, like this:

```
 typedef union
 {
     struct
     {
         short int a;
         short int b;
         short int c;
         short int d;
     } str1;
     short int *my_array;
 } union1;
```

That way you could do:

```
union1 foo;
foo.my_array = malloc(bar * sizeof(short int));
```

I've removed the inner `typedef` you used because it served no purpose and caused compiler errors. I assume you meant to use an anonymous `struct`?

Comment: Also, the removal of the `typedef` from the OP's code is important as it doesn't compile without that change.

Comment: @TomFenech: compiles just fine here with `clang` and `-pedantic`?

Comment: The problem here is that the memory space of `str1` and the memory space of `*my_array` will not overlap. So using a `union` here is pointless to begin with.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't specific. I was referring to the inner `typedef` that you've already removed. I get _type name does not allow storage class to be specified_ in clang with the extra `typedef`. I was meaning that you ought to mention the fact you removed it in your answer.

Comment: @barakmanos: the only feasible use I can see for this is for an either/or situation where they want to return exactly-four integers or a big array of them. It is pointless, but it's what the OP asked for.

Comment: @TomFenech: oh, I see. Sorry :-)

Comment: if you allocate to many short ints, you cannot address them with a,b,c,d,etc. vars. Not very nice IMHO?

Comment: @Evert: fair enough, I'm not really sure what the OP intends to do with this. This is a possible solution, not the only one.

Comment: You are `union`ing a struct with 4 shorts with a `short int *`. Probably you want to make `str1` a pointer as well.

Comment: @glglgl: what the *OP* meant to do is beyond me - they just asked to make `my_array` dynamically allocatable, which this does with minimal change to the original code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, but please note that you will not be able to utilize a `union1` array:

```
typedef struct
{
    short a;
    short b;
    short c;
    short d;
}
str1;

typedef union
{
    str1  my_str;
    short my_array[0];
}
union1;

union1* allocate_union1(int additional_size)
{
    return (union1*)malloc(sizeof(union1)+additional_size);
}
```

If you get a compiler warning for the `[0]`, then you may replace it with a `[1]`.